# Access swift code in static lib from ObjC class in .app

Tags: swift4, xcode9

With XCode 9, it's possible to create static libraries which contain swift code. I have successfully created such a static library and accessed the swift code in the library from swift code in an app. But I have not been able to access the swift code in the static lib from ObjC code. I tried to import the static library using both the methods below, but none have worked:

```
@import StaticLib; //gives 'no module found' error
#import <StaticLib/StaticLib-Swift.h> //gives 'no such file' error
```

Any one has been able to successfully use swift from static lib in ObjC? Any help would be really great.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Have you able to resolve it?

Comment: No, there doesn't seem to be a way as of now.